# Set question,a number where the sum of its digits.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

U={$x:13\le x\le40 $and $x \in \mathbb Z$}

R={$x:x$ is a number where the sum of its digits is more than 8 }

find set R.

guys ,how to do this,my english is a little bad,what means a number where the sum of its digits？

thanks

Comment: The sum of the digits means literally that.  If, say, you start with $x=247$ the sum of digits is $d(x)=2+4+7=13$.  I assume that you want to find the intersection $R \cap U$.

Comment: U ∩ R={18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 39}

Comment: thanks guysvery appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Sum of digits mean if we have 18 so sum of its digits = 1+8 = 9 greater than 8.

R ∩ U= { 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38,39}